# jQuery error in IE: Unexpected call to method or property

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, slider

i got a message same as [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-error-in-ie-unexpected-call-to-method-or-property)

here is [my page](http://cloudpeople.atwebpages.com/pricing_model.php)

No problem with chrome

I suspect the following code which may be causing the problem

```
           function update_cost(){
              var cost = $( "#amount_CPU" ).val() * CPU_per_unit +
                         $( "#amount_RAM" ).val() * RAM_per_unit +
                         $( "#amount_storage" ).val() * storage_per_unit +
                         $( "#amount_traffic" ).val() * traffic_per_unit;
              $( "#estimated_cost" ).text( "$" + cost );
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a tag in there that's misspelled around your "estimated_cost" label:

```
<lable id="estimated_cost"></lable><br />
```

That should be `<label>` not `<lable>`. IE does not know what a "lable" element is so it freaks out.

Comment: Thank you! >_< Stupid, Stupid Me.